# How to distribute blockchain (Networking)

Tags: blockchain, networking

I don't know if this is the correct forum to ask this question, but I am implementing my own blockchain for learning purposes. I now have a simple PoW blockchain.

My problem now is that I don't know how to distribute my blockchain and make the nodes communicate with each other. I am choosing which API to use: REST, JSON-RPC, or WebSocket. What is the best way to go about this?

Let's say I have decided to use one of them, how do I locate other nodes and establish a connection between us? And how do I broadcast a change in the blockchain to the entire network?

I've also heard that there are different types of nodes in the network, and I want to know more about them.

Answer (score 0):

I know some blockchains use libp2p, could be interesting to look into